# Accessing mapped network location to create/copy folders on it using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, permissions, mapped-drive

I have a shared network path that I mapped with my local machine. The parent folder has certain **permissions** set. I have two folders at the root of the mapped location. What I was looking for was to copy the entire directory from one directory to another. Also, while copying this directory, I want to simultaneously set different permissions than that of the parent directory. Additionally, for each copy I should be able to *set different permissions* (i.e. permissions will not be same every time a directory is copied). I would also need to keep a record of which user is copying that directory so that I can set appropriate permissions for each user while copying.

I was able to achieve this using **impersonation**.

Is there a way to achieve this without using impersonation as writing username and password inside wen.config won't be a good idea?

Comment: Give up mapped drives and use UNC paths.

Comment: I tried using UNC paths as well. But still couldn't get through

Comment: Then move on. What do you mean by "writing user name and password in web.config"? Simply enabling ASP.NET impersonation does not require user name or password at all. Just set the boolean value to true.

Comment: I passed the additional parameters for username and password along with the impersonate key in web.config. Without passing the additional parameters it threw access denied error